# Add '\n' to each line of an open file in Python

Tags: python

I have something to send with mail in Python, and I want to add content file in the mail body.

The problem is to add `'\n'` to each line... I've make some tests but each time it puts the `'\n'` after each letter and not line...

Here is the file to add to mail (tests.new):

```
// Files Module
// Module Name
test.cpp
test2.cpp
```

And here is my script :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
newFile = open('tests.new','r')
tNew = newFile.read()
# mail
mail = open('mail.txt', 'w', encoding='utf8')
mail.write("New files in module \n")
# BAD PART
i = len(tNew)
z = 0
while z < i:
        mail.write(str(tNew[z].split('\n')))
        z += 1
        mail.close()
```

The end of the script (after `#BAD PART`) is one of the test I did. It's not obligate to follow this way...

If someone can help me please ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want *duplicated line terminators* in the output file?

Comment: Close the `tests.new` file. You've left the file pointer open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BAD PART problems:

1) `tNew[z]` returns single char, not the line. You need to get lines list first.

2) You close `mail` file in the loop and not open it again.

So the correct code must be:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
newFile = open('tests.new','r')
tNew = newFile.read()
# mail
mail = open('mail.txt', 'w', encoding='utf8')
mail.write("New files in module \n")

# BAD PART - FIXED
lines = tNew.split('\n')
i = len(lines)
z = 0
while z < i:
    mail.write(str(lines[z] + '\n'))
    z += 1
mail.close()
newFile.close()
```

But I'll recommend you to rewrite this code the more Pythonic way:

```
for line in tNew.split('\n'):
    mail.write(line + '\n')
```

Or better:

```
for line in open('tests.new', 'r'):
    mail.write(line + '\n')
```

And you'll not needed to use `z` counter, and `i`.

Comment: `for line in tNew.split('\n'):
    mail.write(line + '\n')` works very well. But now it's Outlook who won't display the line feed ^^. Thanks for help

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is `newFile.read()` reads the entire input file. You then iterate over it byte by byte in your `while` loop and append a newline after each char.
Use the `for line in newFile:` stanza to iterate over lines in the inputfile.

Also your `mail.close()` is in an incorrect place. It is better to use the `with open("somefile.txt") as ifile:` stanza since that takes care of proper file closing after the block ends.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
with open('tests.new','r') as newFile: #this autocloses the file at the end of the block
    with open('mail.txt', 'w', encoding='utf8') as mail: #same
        mail.write("New files in module \n")
        for line in newFile: #iterate over lines in the inputfile instead of over characters
            mail.write("{}\n".format(line))
```